# Protecting public and private APIs in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: rest, api, wso2

I have 5 REST API endpoints that are available for partners. I call them public APIs. I have 10 other REST API endpoints that are consumed only by my website. I call them private APIs. Website also consumes the public APIs.

I don’t want my parters to see my private APIs and my website should be able to use both private and public APIs.

I have an on-premise WSO2 API manager installed on my EC2 instance and want to use it to protect both public and private APIs. What should be the architecture that I should create in WSO2 API Manager? Whether I should create two Stores (One for public APIs and the other for private APIs)? Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easies way IMHO is having role based visibility on APIs.

For your private APIs create a role (e.g. in the carbon console) and in the API definition you can specify which roles will see the APIs in the store